# Finding Images after canvas translation with Multitouch Controller

Tags: android, draggable, drawable, multi-touch

I am using the Multitouch Controller made by Luke Hutchison found here 
https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/

My problem is this.  I can place an image onto the canvas.  I can select it, move it, rotate it and scale it perfectly fine.  The problem is I also allow the user to move the canvas by translating it on drag.  On the screen the images seem to appear in the correct location following the translation of the entire canvas.  The problem is trying to select them afterwards.

I don't know if it's an issue with the touch point after the canvas translation not taking into account the new canvas location/offset or the location of the images haven't been updated with the canvas translation.  Does anyone have any experience with this or be able to point me in the right direction!?